# Move files in Visual Studio and AnkhSVN simultaneously

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, svn, ankhsvn

I'm reorganizing my project in visual studio. I have some `.cpp`/`.h` files which I want to move into a subdirectory physically. A would like to have the following acts simultaneously:

- File moving on file system
- SVN working copy database updating (with keeping history)
- Visual Studio project file(s) updating

Extra benefits would be nice, like:

- Updating of `#include` directives referring to the file.

Are there any solutions? Best workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the proverbial chicken-and-egg dilemma for software developers:

- Do you move/rename your files in Visual Studio first then go back to Windows Explorer and correct all the adds/deletes that should really be renames/moves?
- Or do you rename/move your files in Windows Explorer then go clean up all the introduced compilation errors in Visual Studio?

*You already have the solution at hand!* Without AnkhSVN if you do your file operations in Visual Studio you already get two of your requirements: updating your VS project and file system synchronization. With AnkhSVN installed, though, you also get your 3rd requirement: it makes the necessary SVN synchronizations as well. All you have left to do is a commit.

Answer (score 1):

I found the following description from a [cached page](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aY9ElygOuKvMJ%3awww.williablog.net/williablog/post/2011/05/25/Moving-Files-in-Visual-Studio-and-SVN.aspx%20refresh%20visual%20studio%20project%20after%20moving%20files&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&client=browser-ubuntu) in a Google search:

> In Windows Explorer, right-click and drag the file from its old
>   location to its new location, then select "SVN move versioned item"
>   from the context menu. This will not only move the actual file itself,
>   but it will also make sure that all the file history stays with it
>   after you check in your changes. Back in Visual Studio, use the
>   Solution Explorer in VS2010 to "exclude from project" the
>   (now-missing) copy of the file in its old location, and then "include
>   in project" the file in its new location. You may need to refresh the
>   view in solution explorer and/or make sure you are viewing all the
>   files by clicking the "Show all Files" icon at the top (next to the
>   refresh icon) in order to see these files.
>
> After you update the namespace to reflect the new location, I
>   recommend using a global find and replace before you try to compile to
>   save yourself a lot of trouble.

Hope this helps.