# How can I un-quagmirize my rearranged project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn, tortoisesvn, explorer

Using the following steps (taken from page 39 of "*Pragmatic Guide to Subversion*"):

```
* Using Windows Explorer, right-drag the file to a different location in your working copy, and choose "SVN Move versioned item(s) here."

* Commit your changes by right-clicking the base of your working copy and choosing SVN Commit...
```

...I moved several files into new folders I created within my project (Classes, Data, Forms).

When I then re-loaded the project in Visual Studio and mashed F6, I got five of these err msgs:

*Unable to create a manifest resource name for "ChosenPlatypi.resx". Could not find file 'C:\duckBills\duckBills\ChosenPlatypi.cs'.*

So I saw that all of the files that I had moved over in Explorer were NOT in their folders in the Solution Explorer, but were in their previous location (directly below the project), but now with a red x and a yellow warning icon on them.

So I tried dragging them into the folders I had created (which I had already done in Windows Explorer), but that gives me the error, "*The source file ChosenPlatypi.cs could not be found*"

### UPDATE

So I decided to "start over" by reversing the changes (In Windows Explorer, right-clicked the base/trunk directory, selected Tortoise SVN | Show Log, highlighted the change that wreaked the mayhem, and selected "Revert changes from this revision."

The solution in Visual Studio now compiles again, BUT the files that I had previously moved into new subfolders I created are decoated with a yellow plus sign and, beneath those, red pinwheel (or ...????) icons/glyphs.

ONE of the subfolders I created is still there (Forms), and ONE of the file sets (*.cs, *.Designer.cs, and *.resx) I copied into it is still there. I don't know what, if anything, I did differently with that file move...

Comment: I have to disagree with @akton's first suggestion of moving/renaming in the repository--that will not alleviate the quagmire in VS at all. He touches upon the correct technique at the end, though: use a VS plugin to do moves/renames from within VS and everything else falls into place--for more, see my answer at [Move files in Visual Studio and AnkhSVN simultaneously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12405538/move-files-in-visual-studio-and-ankhsvn-simultaneously/), which is essentially the same question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you move the files in the Apache Subversion repository or on the file system (i.e. on the disk)? If you are moving or renaming files, do it in the repository and then update your local working copy.

If you have moved them on the file system, the **"red X"** icon means the file has been deleted and the **"yellow warning icon"** means a conflict that you should resolve. See [Tortoise SVN explorer integration](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-wcstatus.html#tsvn-dug-wcstatus-dia-1) for more information.

After backing up any important changes, resolve any conflicts and then commit the changes for all the folders affected. Remember that the *history is still present* in the repository and you can just update to an earlier revision if needed.

If you intend to rename or move files around in a Visual Studio solution, consider using a Visual Studio plug-in like [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/) or [AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) to make this much easier within the IDE. Moving them in the solution explorer will be much easier and hassle-free.

Comment: I do have AnkhSVN installed, but haven't actually used it yet; would you happen to know the steps to accomplish this (or fix what I've already tried) using that tool?

Comment: I have expanded my answer. I think you just need to resolve any conflicts (edit the files as needed) then commit your changes.

Comment: On disk/in Windows Explorer, all the icons look good (green check marks). In VS Solution Explorer, they have changed from red Xs and yellow warning signs to blue question marks and yellow warning signs...

Comment: I guess I will revert to the pre-rearranged locations and start over. Windows Explorer has it right, and if I try to add files in Solution Explorer to where they should be and really are (by right-clicking on the "Classes" folder, for instance, and select Add | Existing Item, the file I want to move is already seen as being there, although the folder appears to be empty from Solution Explorer).