# How to add folders and move files into them in VS using AnkhSVN?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn, tortoisesvn, explorer, ankhsvn

I tried accomplishing this using tortoise, but failed and reverted to my prior commit ([How can I un-quagmirize my rearranged project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12699828/how-can-i-un-quagmirize-my-rearranged-project))

How can I add subfolders to my project and have them be recognized by Visual Studio AND Subversion?

Simply adding folders in Solution Explorer and dragging-and-dropping the files in Windows Explorer did not work.

It seems I can either add the files to the subfolders in Windows Explorer, but not have that rearrangement of file location recognized in Visual Studio's Solution Explorer, OR I can drag-and-drop the files within Visual Studio's Solution Explorer to the new subfolders, but that relocation is not recognized in Windows Explorer.

I HAVE re-added the subfolders within Visual Studio (I figure that can't break anything, while they are empty, anyway). Would right-clicking a file and selecting Refactor | Move be an accepted way to get this to work (I reckon the Refactor context menu item comes from Resharper, but possibly it's a VS "thing").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If at least one file is into a directory and this file was added via AnkhSVN (Subversion > Add), the directory will be automatically added as well.

If the directory is empty, even if the directory is included in the solution, the Add command via AnkhSVN will not work. This is a weird behaviour you can workaround using another SVN Client like [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net).